# No sound after installing "gnome-media"

Tags: sound

How do I revert whatever gnome media has done? I ran `sudo apt-get purge gnome-media` to uninstall the package but it doesn't seem to work. ...seems like it tampered with the defaults or something. Any help appreciated. I'm using an LXDE in 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay [that](http://utdream.org/post.cfm/resetting-pulseaudio-on-ubuntu-13-04-new-sound-card) worked. Reinstalling Pulseaudio (which resets things to defaults).

To cut to the chase just type in these commands in a terminal in order.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
sudo alsa force-reload
rm -rf ~/.config/pulse
sudo reboot
```

(restarts computer)

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
pavucontrol
```